# How to change value of a cell in a table model in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I created a class inheriting from AbstractTableModel. I want to override setValueAt(), so that it will change the value of the cell in row `r` and column `c` into the multidimensional array `v`. But I keep getting errors.

```
public class ItemListTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

public void setValueAt(Object v, int r, int c) {  
    rowData[r][c] = v;// This is where the error is.
    fireTableCellUpdated(r, c);  
}  

@Override
public int getRowCount() {

}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {

}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

}

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){ 
    return true; 
}  

}
```

Comment: elaborate your question with precise error/output.

Comment: What areas? What is and how is `rowData` declared?

Comment: My IDE said it "cannot find symbol"

Comment: Where (does your IDE say this), what line?

Comment: On rowData[row][col] = value;

Comment: rowData[row][col] = value; Error ecause you have no rowData variable in the class. make ItemListTableModel  a Inner class of the rowdata owner class.

Comment: See this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Sorry if I made you confused, I have just realized that `rowData` doesn't exist. Basically I want to set the value of the cell on row `r` and column `c` into `v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractTableModel` has no concept of the content of the model or how it's managed, that's kind of the point.  It's designed to allow developers to design their own models based on their own complex requirements.

A simpler solution would be to use a `DefaultTableModel`, which provides all the functionality out of the box...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns); // you need to define rows and columns for yourself
model.setValueAt(row, column, value); // Again, you need to define the variables for your self
```

Should you "absolutely" need a custom table model based on `AbstractTableModel`, then you will need to provide the storage mechanisms which are used to store data within a given row/data yourself.

Typically, I define a POJO which represents the row and then add these to some kind of `List`, as it provides a simple mechanism for growing and shrinking the model

Answer (score 0):

In your class you haven't declared the type of `rowData`.  Presumably it's an 2 x 2 `int` array, but you haven't declared it, so the compiler cannot find the identifier.  What you want to do is first declare `rowData` like

```
int[][] rowData = new int[r][v];
```

Then you can assign `v` to `rowData` as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Example use of `AbstractTableModel::setValueAt()`.

```
    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private final String[] columnNames = new String[]{"Col One", "Col Two"};
        private final Object[][] data = new String[][]{new String[]{"R1C1", "R1C2"}, new String[]{"R2C1", "R2C2"}};

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
......
rest of the code
```